# Standalone Babel and using arrow functions plugin?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, babeljs

I'm building an App in a non-node environment but I want to make use of Babel's ES6 transpiling so that I can write somewhat nicer code and still support IE11.

So I went ahead and included the standalone file found here:
https://github.com/babel/babel/tree/master/packages/babel-standalone

But it seems like you also need an additional plugin to actually transpile arrow function syntax, but of course because I don't have access to the import/export module features I'm not sure if it is even possible to include these plugins.

Does anyone know a way around this?

Comment: *It's bundled with all the standard Babel plugins and presets* - so, it should work out of the box according to the readme

Comment: Hmm, I've set the ES version to 2017 and IE is still throwing unsupported syntax errors. Object.assign also doesn't work :/

Comment: Babel compiles syntax only, if you want `Object.assign` you'd always want to load a polyfill like babel-polyfill.

Comment: You're right - even IE11 borks (without the polyfill)

Comment: @loganfsmyth Well I mostly was looking to use arrow functions, I just don't think it's possible without including a plugin which I also don't think is possible using inline script tags because of the lack of module support in browsers.

Comment: as I said, *all the standard Babel plugins and presets* are bundled with `standalone/babel.js` - not sure why you ignore this fact. So, arrow functions work if you load `<script src="https://unpkg.com/@babel/polyfill/browser.js"></script>` and `<script src="https://unpkg.com/@babel/standalone/babel.js"></script>` - and then your scripts should be `<script type="text/babel" ... </script>`

Comment: You don't have to load the plugin. The whole point of standalone is that they are all included, you just have to enable them. How are you actually calling Babel-standalone to compile the files?

Comment: I was doing pretty much exactly what Jaromanda said above, including the standalone script files in inline script tags and then including my JS in a script tag with the type set to text\babel. Also I read they changed the Babel standalone so that ES2015 features aren't included by default and are now opt-in features.

Comment: Alrighty, so apparently Object.assign works using the browser polyfill Jaromanda recommended, IE is still not happy about arrow functions unfortunately.

Comment: Right, so are you opting into any features? The documentation for babel-standalone has examples of how to enable presets: https://github.com/babel/babel-standalone#usage And Babel's general documentation would have everything about what those presets do.

Comment: if IE is *still not happy about arrow functions* then you are probably using script tags with the wrong `type` ... they **must** be `type="text/babel"`

Comment: I've set the data-preset as es2015, tried setting the data-plugin attribute to use the arrow functions plugin but it didn't recognize it.

Comment: I understand they must be text/babel, I've made sure they are :)

Comment: Please include that code in the question. If you keep telling us without actually showing, I'm not sure how we're expected to answer.

Comment: `it didn't recognize it` what didn't recognise  what? You're doing something wrong ... just a though, babel and polyfill script tags **must not be** `text/babel`

Answer (score 2):

As you have shown ZERO code in the question, and you're going on about setting this preset or that preset (blah blah blah), I can only assume you're doing something wrong

This HTML works in IE

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Home</title>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/@babel/polyfill/browser.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/@babel/standalone/babel.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="output"></div>
    <script type="text/babel">
      const getMessage = () => "Hello World";
      document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = getMessage();
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

How does it compare with what you are doing?